# Rails Instance Method with if/else on empty field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wrote an instance method in my model for calculating a time difference between two dates. Works when the second date exists, but need to add an `if else` condition to return a string if the second date does not exist. I have

```
class Incident  
def calculate_elapsed(difference)
if self.closed.nil?
  @difference = "Open"
else
  d1 = self.created
  d2 = self.closed
  difference = d2 - d1
  @difference = difference.to_i
end
```

When I try to load an Incident which I know to have an empty `closed` date I get

`You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!`

`You might have expected an instance of Array.`

`The error occurred while evaluating nil.-`

Puzzled by the error because I figured `if self.closed.nil?`
was checking for the nil object. What can I do to get this to work?

I'm not certain this is the right way to handle what I'm trying to do, so open to any and all suggestions (i.e. this should be a class method, helper, etc. Had it in my controller previously and figured this was a step in the right direction).

What's further confusing is that I can call this method in a partial and it returns the "Open" string wherever the closed date does not exist.

**Edit**

Here's what I got working-

Model:

```
class Incident  
def calculate_elapsed
if self.closed.blank?
  @difference = "Complaint Open"
else
  d1 = created
  d2 = closed
  difference = d2 - d1
  difference_clean = difference.to_i
  @difference = difference_clean.to_s + ' Days'
end 
end
```

show.html.erb

```
<%= @incident.calculate_elapsed %>
```

_incidents.html.erb partial

```
<%= incident.calculate_elapsed %>
```

Comment: Could you please post a full stacktrace?

Comment: full stacktrace here - [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/fxbCNi7E) Please do let me know if this isn't what you were looking for. Should I always post this?

Comment: the error is at line 9, have you checked that line?

Comment: line 9 in incident.rb is `d1 = self.created` seems fine to me?

Comment: `self` is always defined. have tried to restart your application? maybe the class is outdated in your Rails environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error should be somewhere else, because `nil?` method is defined on Objects and `nil` is also an object.

As my last comment probably helped, possibly your class definition in you Rails environment was outdated, so restarting the application forced Rails to reload the source.

You can also reload the classes with [`reload!`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-reload-21) method for e.g. in Rails console.

Comment: Not really sure what did it, but your suggestions of `self` being always defined and restarting my application for the outdated class in the environment helped me get this apparently solved. Thanks!